# Unique Post Meta Values

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, mysql

I want to use Unique IDs like YouTube video IDs and WordPress post IDs in a custom field 'youtube_id'. I just created a front-end add post page and want to check if 'youtube_id' used or not used in a older post.

```
    $title = 'blah blah blah';
    $different=mysql_query("SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title='$title'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($different)>0) {
    echo 'Dude, we already have this post.';
    }
```

this code looks for post title is unique or not. I need something similar with this. But I need to use postmeta, not post_title.

Any idea to check it with WordPress functions or mysql?

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be complicated so I can't help but think that I am missing something. What it sounds like you need is [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

```
$yid = get_post_meta($post->ID,'youtube_id',true);
if (empty($yid)) {
  // not set
} else {
  // set
}
```

Edit:

You need a `meta_query` for the most WordPress-y solution:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'youtube_id',
      'value' => 'some_value',
    )
  ),
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'no_found_rows' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'fields' => 'ids',
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q);
```

However, your code is easily adaptable:

```
$different = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'youtube_id' AND meta_value = 'some_value'");
if(!empty($different)) {
    echo 'Dude, we already have this post.';
}
```

Note: use `$wpdb`. It will save you some effort.

Comment: Thanks but it won't help me. It looks **a post** has post meta. I need to look **every posts** to check the new post is unique or not.

Comment: I sympathize with the language barrier, but it is not clear what you are trying to do. Please edit to question with more detail.

Comment: Ok, I added an example.